# How to find the vertex of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The parabola $y=-x(x-2)$ is concave down, find the vertex.

Comment: "I'm aware that to find the y-intercept you make $x=0$": so do you have any problems substituting $x=0$?

Comment: Edit: I dont mean the y intercept i mean the vertex

Comment: @Xardous could you edit the question so it states what you are after? right now the title says you seek the $y$ intercept and in the comments you say something else also there are two different versions of the equation in the body. My answer below aimed to help finding the vertex

Comment: Since the expression is in factored form, you know the $x$-intercepts of the parabola are $0$ and $2$.  The $x$-coordinate of the vertex is the average of the $x$-intercepts.

Comment: [How To Ask A Homework Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

The axis of symmetry for a parabola  of the form
$$
y=ax^2+bx+c
$$ 
is given by the equation
$$
x = -\frac{b}{2a}.
$$
Can you figure out the rest?